# Is improving a Neural Network really just "trial and error"?

Tags: python, neural-network, convergence

I am a PhD student in Computational Physics and I've started to study a bit of Neural Networks, and decided to try and use some of what I've learned for a problem I'm having. After some studying, I've understood how to build a Neural Network for my purpose, but I can't find relevant info about how to build a *good* Neural Network apart from the good old [trial and error](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fuck%20Around%20And%20Find%20Out). Here I attach the NN I'm currently working with as an example, but my question applies to the general case of a (regression) neural network: **is there some theory on why I should build an architecture instead of another one, what activator I should choose, why I should lower my learning rate and how much, why should my dropout rate be higher and how much, how much training data is enough**, and all these sorts of things?

My NN takes as input a 2x7 array of real values in [0,1] and gives as output a single real value, and it looks like this:

```py
model_cnn = Sequential()
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 7, 1), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
model_cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (2, 2), activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
model_cnn.add(Flatten())
model_cnn.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model_cnn.add(Dense(128, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
model_cnn.add(Dropout(0.5)) 
model_cnn.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model_cnn.add(BatchNormalization())
model_cnn.add(Dense(1, activation='linear')) #linear for regression

def lr_schedule(epoch):
    lr = 1e-3
    if epoch > 50:
        lr *= 0.1
    if epoch > 100:
        lr *= 0.1
    return lr

lr_scheduler = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                        patience=20, 
                        restore_best_weights=True)

model_cnn.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule(0)),
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

nn_history = model_cnn.fit(X_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=64,
                        epochs=1000,
                        verbose=1,
                        validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                        callbacks=[lr_scheduler, early_stopping])
```

This is the result of some adjustments, for example adding dropout and normalization, that I did just by feeling, without any actual knowledge of, for example, whether it is correct to put them in the above order. Again: I know I can just try to change it and see what happens, but I'm asking how (if there is a way!) to decide what are the plausible, if not the best, things to do.
As of now, the loss-vs-epoch looks like this:

[image]

Doesn't look too bad, but I would like the loss to converge to zero (or at least to a value closer to zero). How can I understand what things are "worth trying"?

Comment: Your number of parameters to be fitted should be smaller than the number of samples, else you risk overfitting. An almost optimal descent direction and step length is obtained from Newton or Gauß-Newton. However the dimension is the amount of parameters, so that is largely not realistic, thus the use of gradient descent and that broken up into stochastic gradient descent. The controllers like Adam try to heuristically reconstruct an appropriate step size. It is my understanding that you largely do not need to regulate the learning rate, only have it small at the start to avoid overshooting.

Comment: Note that this question is off-topic, tuning a neural network architecture is not a programming problem, people should not be upvoting off-topic questions.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm sorry if my question is off-topic: I thought that since I'm programming after all (I'm building this in python, not with pen and paper) it would be good. Could you help/address me regarding where to post it/how to make it on-topic?

Comment: You should post in https://ai.stackexchange.com/ or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/, when you do, you should delete the question here.